# Почему не работает выпадающий список?

Tags: javascript, html, css

```js
var dropDown = document.querySelectorAll('.drop_down_lists');
for (var i=0; i < dropDown.length; i++) {
 if(dropDown[i].addEventListener) {
  dropDown[i].addEventListener('click', function() {
   if(this.lastChild.previousSibling.style.display == 'none') {
    this.lastChild.previousSibling.style.display = 'block';
    this.firstChild.nextSibling.style.color = '#ff7519';
   };
  })
 }
}
```

```css
.main_content .repeat_aside{float:left;background-color:#4c4b4b;width:270px;margin-top:24px;padding-top:28px;padding-bottom:200px}.main_content .repeat_aside .icon-home{color:#fff;font-size:28px;margin-left:24px}.main_content .repeat_aside .icon-home:hover{color:#ff7519;transition:.2s}.main_content .repeat_aside .drop_down_lists{margin-top:18px;border-left:5px solid #ff7519}.main_content .repeat_aside .drop_down_lists h2{margin-left:24px;color:#fff;font-size:20px}.main_content .repeat_aside .drop_down_lists .hidden_drop_down{margin-top:10px;display:none}.main_content .repeat_aside .drop_down_lists .hidden_drop_down a{display:block;text-decoration:none;color:#b8b8b8;font-size:16px;font-weight:700;margin-left:40px;line-height:30px}.main_content .repeat_aside .drop_down_lists .hidden_drop_down a:hover{color:#ff7519;transition:.2s}
```

```html
<section class="main_content">
  <div class="container">
   <aside class="repeat_aside">
    <i class="icon-home"></i>
    <div class="drop_down_lists">
     <h2>Профиль компании<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></h2>
     <div class="hidden_drop_down">
      <a href="#">Основные сведения</a>
      <a href="#">Настройки аккаунта</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop_down_lists">
     <h2>Объявления<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></h2>
     <div class="hidden_drop_down">
      <a href="#">о продаже</a>
      <a href="#">о покупке</a>
      <a href="#">предложение  услуг</a>
      <a href="#">заказ услуг</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop_down_lists">
     <h2>Сообщения<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></h2>
     <div class="hidden_drop_down">
      <a href="#">Предложения</a>
      <a href="#">Заявки</a>
      <a href="#">Исходящие</a>
      <a href="#">От администрации</a>
      <a href="#">Прайс-листы</a>
      <a href="#">Спам</a>
     </div>
    </div>
    <div class="drop_down_lists">
     <h2>Контакты<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></h2>
     <div class="hidden_drop_down">
      <a href="#">Статус компании</a>
      <a href="#">Статус компании</a>
     </div>     
    </div>
    <div class="drop_down_lists">
     <h2>Торговые сервисы<i class="icon-arrow-down"></i></h2>
     <div class="hidden_drop_down">
      <a href="#">Статус компании</a>
      <a href="#">Прайс-лист</a>
      <a href="#">Подписки</a>
      <a href="#">Шаблоны</a>
      <a href="#">Анализ рынка</a>
     </div>
    </div>
   </aside>
  </div>
 </section>
```

Не работает выпадающий список при добавлении `if(this.lastChild.previousSibling.style.display == 'none')` без этого оператора сравнения все работает, видимо `this` внутри `if` как-то по другому работает, но я не понимаю как

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Сравнивать надо так `if(this.lastChild.previousSibling.style.display == '')`.
Вообще лучше использовать делегирование и избегать вот этого в условии `dropDown[i].addEventListener` .  `This` внутри обработчика события ссылается на текущий элемент, то есть на тот, на котором он сработал.Таких условий тоже лучше избегать `this.lastChild.previousSibling.style.display`. По разметке я бы сделал меню списком.  Вообщем удалите вот этот селектор `.main_content .repeat_aside .drop_down_lists .hidden_drop_down{margin-top:10px;display:none}` и добавьте в css:

```
.hidden_drop_down {
    display: block;
    margin-top:10px;
}
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

в html добавьте каждому блоку класс `hidden` во так `<div class="hidden_drop_down hidden">`
js можно сделать так:

```
let menu = document.addEventListener('click', showMenu);
    function showMenu(e) {
    if(e.target.tagName !== 'H2') return;
    e.target.parentElement.querySelector('.hidden_drop_down').classList.toggle('hidden');
    }
```